# Salesforce Omnichannel Inventory API

Tags: rest-api, api, b2c

Does anyone have more detailed documentation on the Omnichannel Inventory APIs? I'm trying to get an example of a call to get stock availability, but the docs are not very comprehensive.

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_oci_availability_records_get_availability.htm) you need to do a POST call to:
`/commerce/oci/availability/availability-records/actions/get-availability`

with the below body:

```
{
    "locationGroupIdentifiers": ["{{location_group_id}}"],
    "stockKeepingUnits": ["{{product_sku}}"],
    "useCache": {{use_cache}}
}
```

So my question is, if I want to get the available stock for a specific SKU at a specific location, what do I send in the call to identify the specific SKU? Product Code? SF RecordId?
And what does the response look like?

Any help will be appreciated. Even a Postman Collection with some more details would be amazing!

Comment: Have you tried the [sf-oci-postman-collection](https://github.com/jbachelet/sf-oci-postman-collection/tree/master/Core%20Platform%20APIs) ?

Comment: Yes I have, but had a whole heap of trouble getting it to authenticate. Finally was able to do successful calls today. and got some response. Will post them in the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, if anyone wants to see an example request and response, here you go. This is for querying a specific stock item in an inventory group. It then returns information for all stock locations.

Request:
POST {{_instance_url}}/services/data/v{{version}}/commerce/oci/availability/availability-records/actions/get-availability

Request Body:

```
{
    "locationGroupIdentifier": "all_inventory",
    "stockKeepingUnit": "1234"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "errors": [],
    "locationGroups": [
        {
            "inventoryRecords": [
                {
                    "availableToFulfill": 197.0,
                    "availableToOrder": 197.0,
                    "effectiveDate": "2022-08-19T08:50:29.749Z",
                    "futures": [],
                    "onHand": 199.0,
                    "reserved": 2.0,
                    "safetyStockCount": 0.0,
                    "stockKeepingUnit": "1234"
                }
            ],
            "locationGroupIdentifier": "all_inventory"
        }
    ],
    "locations": [
        {
            "inventoryRecords": [
                {
                    "availableToFulfill": 197.0,
                    "availableToOrder": 197.0,
                    "effectiveDate": "2022-08-19T08:50:29.749Z",
                    "futures": [],
                    "onHand": 199.0,
                    "reserved": 2.0,
                    "safetyStockCount": 0.0,
                    "stockKeepingUnit": "1234"
                }
            ],
            "locationIdentifier": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "inventoryRecords": [
                {
                    "availableToFulfill": 0.0,
                    "availableToOrder": 0.0,
                    "effectiveDate": "2022-08-19T08:50:29.749Z",
                    "futures": [],
                    "onHand": 0.0,
                    "reserved": 0.0,
                    "safetyStockCount": 0.0,
                    "stockKeepingUnit": "1234"
                }
            ],
            "locationIdentifier": "DEF"
        },
        {
            "inventoryRecords": [
                {
                    "availableToFulfill": 0.0,
                    "availableToOrder": 0.0,
                    "futures": [],
                    "onHand": 0.0,
                    "reserved": 0.0,
                    "safetyStockCount": 0.0,
                    "stockKeepingUnit": "1234"
                }
            ],
            "locationIdentifier": "XYZ"
        }
    ],
    "success": true
}
```